# xlPercentOfTotal is calculating % of Total (whole data set instead of grand total value in pivot table)

Tags: excel, vba

Issue:

using .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal to try to show the cell values in a Pivot Table column as % of Grand Total.

Current Output:

It is instead calculating everything as a % (including grand total) from the whole data set in the column rather than just using the Grand Total in the Pivot Table.
(Last row, 15 is Grand Total)

```
Value    Desired Output
4            .2667%
1            .0667%
2            .1333%
4            .2667%
4            .2667%
15            1%
```

Desired Output:

The desired result should be the same as manually right clicking the column in the Pivot Table and 'Show Values As' ... 'Percent of Grand Total'.
(Last row, 15 is Grand Total)

```
Value    Desired Output
4            26.67%
1            6.67%
2            13.33%
4            26.67%
4            26.67%
15            100%
```

The desired result should be the same as manually right clicking the column in the Pivot Table and 'Show Values As' ... 'Percent of Grand Total'.

Current Affected Code Block:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("ColumnName")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlCount
.Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
.NumberFormat = "General\%;-"
.Name = "ThisIsTheColumnName"
End With
```

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is, I suspect as I have previously encountered it is due to formatting but I am a bit lost.

EDIT:

I think I may have found an issue.

```
.NumberFormat = "General\%;-"
```

This I guess takes the percent value and then divides it again or something similar giving me a percentage of a percent (ie 100% of 100% is 1%).

The reason I had that in there is because I originally wanted all NULL values to be a '-' (hyphen).

Commenting out that line produces the desired result, but then removes the ability for catching NULL values  as '-'.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("ColumnName")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlCount
.Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
.NumberFormat = "General\%;-"
.Name = "ThisIsTheColumnName"
End With
```

Comment: In `.NumberFormat = "General\%;-" `, `General\%` does not apply a percentage format, but append a '%' symbol to a general format. Maybe you want "0.0%;-"?

Comment: @VincentG You are correct. I have been, again, bamboozled by number formatting in excel. Thank you very much.